# Handling Scroll in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

I'm building a React app, and one of the main features will be a full-screen title page. When the user scrolls on the title page, the page automatically scrolls down and the header bar sticks to the top. I do not want the body overflow hidden here, because as soon as I go to put the overflow back in, the scrollbar will appear and the whole page jolts left about 5px.

I've seen this feature a lot; it's pretty common for single-page web designs. However, I can't seem to get it right. I've gotten to a decent point where the app will scroll for you, but it always bugs out when I try to scroll in the middle of the automatic scroll. This is the closest I've gotten to a solution:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Scroll from 'react-scroll';

class Header extends Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        scrolling: false,
        inLogo: false,
        sticky: "",
        lastScrollPos: 0
    }
    /* Must bind to access 'this' */
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    this.isScrollingDown = this.isScrollingDown.bind(this);

    this.scroller = Scroll.animateScroll;
}

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    Scroll.Events.scrollEvent.register('end', function(to, element) {
        this.state.scrolling = false;
        if(!this.state.inLogo) {
            this.setState({sticky: "sticky"});
        }
    }.bind(this));

    if(window.pageYOffset < 150) {
        this.state.inLogo = true;
        this.scroller.scrollToTop();
    } else {
        this.state.inLogo = false;
        this.scroller.scrollTo(window.innerHeight);
    }
}
componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.state.scrolling) {
        if(this.state.inLogo) {
            this.scroller.scrollToTop();
        } else {
            this.scroller.scrollTo(window.innerHeight);
        }
    }
}

handleScroll(e) {
    console.log(this.state.scrolling);
    if(this.state.scrolling) {
        return;
    }
    var scrollDown = this.isScrollingDown();
    var inLogo = this.isInLogo();
    if(inLogo) {
        if(scrollDown) {
            console.log("Scrolling down in logo");
            this.setState({
                scrolling: true,
                inLogo: false
            });
        }
        if(!scrollDown) {
            console.log("Scrolling up in logo");
            this.setState({
                scrolling: true,
                inLogo: true,
                sticky: ""
            });
        }
    }
}

isScrollingDown() {
    var scrollingDown = window.pageYOffset > this.state.lastScrollPos;
    this.state.lastScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    return scrollingDown;
}

isInLogo() {
    return window.pageYOffset > 150 && window.pageYOffset < window.innerHeight;
}

render() {
    return (
        <div id="app-header" className={"header "+this.state.sticky}>
            <div className="header-filler"></div>
            <a href="#contactUs"><button>Contact Us</button></a>
            <a href="#firstSection"><button>First</button></a>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

The problem here is that when you scroll in the middle of an automatic scroll, the `"end"` scroll event in `react-scroll` is fired. So, the callback for the `"end"` scroll even sets `this.state.scrolling` to false. Now, since that's false, the scroll is handled and I `setState()` again, potentially making the header bar sticky.

**Bottom line**: the ideal solution is to disable the scroll in `componentDidUpdate` when it begins scrolling, and enable it again in the `"end"` event handler. The problem with this solution is this event handler is called when the user interrupts an automatic scroll.

Lastly, I've found some methods on stackoverflow to disable/enable scrolling, but I took them out because they didn't seem to help the `"end"` event handling issue. It just re-enables the scrolling anyway when the handler is fired.

Please ask questions, I'm trying really hard to explain this clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to basically "continue" the scroll in my `'end'` event handler if it is called before the scroll is actually finished. Here is the updated code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Scroll from 'react-scroll';

class Header extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    //scroll direction: (1) - down, (2) - up
    this.state = {
        scrolling: false,
        inLogo: false,
        sticky: "",
        lastScrollPos: 0
    }
    /* Must bind to access 'this' */
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
    this.scroller = Scroll.animateScroll;
    this.isScrollingDown = this.isScrollingDown.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    Scroll.Events.scrollEvent.register('end', function() {
        if(window.pageYOffset == 0) {
            console.log("End: "+window.pageYOffset);
            this.setState({sticky: "", scrolling: false});
        }
        else if(window.pageYOffset == window.innerHeight) {
            console.log("End: "+window.pageYOffset);
            this.setState({sticky: "sticky", scrolling: false});
        } else {
            if(this.state.inLogo) {
                this.scroller.scrollToTop();
            } else {
                this.scroller.scrollTo(window.innerHeight);
            }
        }
    }.bind(this));

    if(window.pageYOffset < 150) {
        this.state.inLogo = true;
        this.scroller.scrollTo(0);
    } else {
        this.state.inLogo = false;
        this.scroller.scrollTo(window.innerHeight);
    }
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.state.scrolling) {
        if(this.state.inLogo) {
            this.scroller.scrollToTop();
        } else {
            this.scroller.scrollTo(window.innerHeight);
        }
    }
  }

  handleScroll(e) {
    console.log(this.state.scrolling);
    if(this.state.scrolling) {
        return;
    }
    var scrollDown = this.isScrollingDown();
    var inLogo = this.isInLogo();
    if(inLogo) {
        if(scrollDown) {
            console.log("Scrolling down in logo");
            this.setState({
                scrolling: true,
                inLogo: false
            });
        }
        if(!scrollDown) {
            console.log("Scrolling up in logo");
            this.setState({
                scrolling: true,
                inLogo: true,
                sticky: ""
            });
        }
    }
  }

  isScrollingDown() {
    var scrollingDown = window.pageYOffset > this.state.lastScrollPos;
    this.state.lastScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    return scrollingDown;
  }

  isInLogo() {
    return window.pageYOffset > 150 && window.pageYOffset < window.innerHeight - 5;
  }
```